# DataFrame's line cannot extract correctly

Tags: python, pandas

DataFrame's line cannot extract correctly.
Now my codes is

```
df_train = pd.read_csv("Desktop/t.csv")
df_train.head()
df_train_y = pd.read_csv("Desktop/z.csv")
df_train_y.head()
csv_data = pd.concat([df_train, df_train_y],axis=1)
csv_data.head(50)
```

But data was shown data.

[image]

I do not want have the part of red square, but I do not know how to delete it.I tried this code

```
csv_data.loc[['121':'11'],:]
```

but

```
  File "<ipython-input-18-d06f9976e765>", line 1
    csv_data.loc[['121':'11'],:]
                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

error happens.
How can I achieve my goal?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have two things wrong, first argument for .loc is for rows, the second is for columns. And you don't need the inner brackets.

So, try this.

```
csv_data.loc[:,'121':'11']
```

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,100,(6,10)))

df.columns = ['0','1','0','3','0','5','6','7','8','9']

df.loc[:,'1':'3']
```

Output:

```
    1   0   3
0  64  18  86
1  19   4  39
2  41  99  20
3  42  90  12
4  86  79  33
5  56  33  14
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me as if the first and third columns are the indices of the respective files.

Also, it looks like your file doesn't have a header.

I'd try this instead:

```
df_train = pd.read_csv("Desktop/t.csv", header=None, index_col=0)
df_train_y = pd.read_csv("Desktop/z.csv", header=None, index_col=0)

csv_data = pd.concat([df_train, df_train_y], axis=1)
```